# Network calls with a transaction

Tags: java, transactions, network-programming

I am using Jave EE, but really I think this would hold true across most technologies.

I always ensure that I don't make network calls to 3rd party services inside of a method annotated with @Transactional.

My reason for doing so is because as I understand it:

1. A transaction should cover as small amount of work as possible.
2. Network timeouts could start causing database issues when the transaction is holding on to resources.

So I always perform the network call first, outside of the transaction. Once that has succeeded, I then start the transaction and update the datastore.

Is this necessary? Is this a good strategy or am I being overly paranoid.

Comment: Primarily opinion based question. You're not doing that without reasons, you have two bullet points already that already answer why it is necessary, I wouldn't know why you need to ask this other than a severe lack in faith in yourself.

Comment: Well, this is something I got taught, but I've never been able to find any info confirming the reasons for doing so. Hence, I would like some real confirmation.

Comment: Well be a good researcher then - do everything in your power to prove that you're wrong. If you can't, you've got a better confirmation than asking random strangers what they think.